# XCode Instruments OpenGL ES Analyzer intrument failed to obtain a reference to the target device?

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, instruments

I am trying to run OpenGL ES Analyzer with my app on iOS Simulator in XCode instruments, but when I click the "record" button in the Instruments toolbar, a warning message comes up saying:

> Device Incompatibility.
>   The OpenGL ES Analyzer instrument failed to obtain a reference to the target device. If you are trying to use this instrument with a wirelessly connected device please make sure "Sync over Wi-Fi connection" is enabled in iTunes.

No analyzer is launched after that. What kind of device incompatibility is it talking about? I never did anything manually with these devices, it has all been installed as single XCode package and updated itself automatically since then. I am not running it wirelessly, i am trying to run it in iOS simulator on the same host macbook.
How to get past that warning?

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGL ES Analyzer instrument does not support the iOS simulator. It only supports iOS devices.